# Can I clock a duration without a start/end time in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I just want to indicate that a task took 2 hours - I don't care when it started or ended, and I'd prefer not to put in false info for that!
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please add a bit more detail about your use case to your post. Are you using Org's clocking commands to record time spent on a task? It sounds like you're not because if you were you wouldn't need to "put in false info". Org would take care of recording timestamps for you (and would also compute the total amount of time spent on a task after clocking out).

Comment: This is for when I am not clocking in and out, but just want to record the total time spent on a task. For example (contrived), if wash dishes and cook at the same time, and want to record that I spent 30 min on each, but there is no real start/end time for either activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such way as of now. Though, if you want to make it easy, and still want to know this is a fake time, I'd clock each time from 0:00 to 2:00 (for example).